# How do I get the list of all the orders that were fulfilled by Amazon on a particular day

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I want to get all the orders that were Fulfilled by Amazon (FBA orders) for a particular date using Amazon MWS API. I tried using the ListOrders API with the CreatedBefore and CreatedAfter parameters but the values returned do not match the values that are obtained from Amazon report for the same day. 
How do I get the list of all the orders that were fulfilled by Amazon on a particular day?

I would really appreciate any help in this. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a filter parameter for that. The closest match would be the LastUpdatedAfter/Before and OrderStatus filters. But if the reports api produces the proper list, you can use that, no?

Comment: I am not able to use the reports API, I have downloaded the reports from our amazon account and tried matching it with my ListOrders API results but there is a mismatch :(

Comment: The CreatedBefore/After are for when the order is created (a customer placed the order). When it's fulfilled is another step (status 'Shipped'), causing the mismatch. You might be able to filter on the shipped date (client side). I'd seriously check out the reports api - it's part of the same MWS lib that the orders api is in. What programming language do you use?

Comment: You are right, I also think I should use the Reports API, not getting exactly which one to use. I am using PHP programming language.

Comment: I use [this mws reports lib](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/bde/reports/v20090101/php.html/177-9975493-5670518). It's a beast, though. Multi-step. First you request a  report, then poll for completion, then download the report. It has sales reports, inventory and what not. For uploading you'll need the [feeds api](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/bde/feeds/v20090101/php.html/192-1611977-6810033). You can explore the api at the [mws scratchpad](https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help @Kenney, I got it now. Can you tell me is there any way to specify the date range for which we need the reports?

Comment: Yes, see the scatchpad - it's a demo of the api capabilities. Select "Reports" in the API Section at the top left, and "RequestReport" in the "Operation" pulldown. Then you'll see under Optional API Parameters a Start Date and End Date. Use [GetReport](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_GetReport.html) with the [report type you need](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__FBAReports), which says you can get a month's worth, updated daily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using the Reports API rather than the Orders API for this.  You will find that you will have throttling issues very quickly using the Orders API.

Use a RequestReport with a report type "_GET_AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENTS_DATA_" with the startDate and endDate fields populated.

If you are unfamiliar with using the reports API, refer to the Amazon API documentation.

[Amazon API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/index.html)

The basic structure of the reporting system is the following:

1. Make a report request using RequestReport operation.
2. Wait for Amazon to process your report.  Check progress by making a GetReportRequestList request and reading the response.
3. Call GetReport with the reportID provided from the GetReportRequestList response.
4. Process the saved file. (which is a tab delimited flat file)

[Link to Amazon Reports API (including samples)](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/177-0704693-5409945?ie=UTF8&group=bde&section=reports&version=latest)

***Edit***

Missed that comment about writing in PHP.  I am currently using this methodology to pull current FBA orders data, but using the C# Libraries.  I would guess the process should be the same.

***Edit***
I agree with the mismatch comments.  Pulling Orders Data from Amazon based on date can be really messy because they have very odd definitions of 'Complete', 'Shipped' etc.  Likewise the orderDate for an order processed in the past 24 hours may be from 2 weeks ago due to what I believe is some oddities in how the Amazon cart works.  IE someone puts something in their cart 2 weeks ago but doesn't purchase, then when the order processes, the orderDate is from 2 weeks ago.  No 100% confirmation that that is the cause, but in any case.. it's actually difficult to get a no nonsense, the orders processed in the past day.

Comment: I am sure that is the correct steps in order to get the reports. I am able to make a report request and get the ReportRequestId, now in 2nd step when I am trying to Check progress by making a GetReportRequestList request, I am getting errors : 1. If I pass the ReportRequestId I get Fatal err: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to construct from provided data. Please be sure to pass associative array or DOMElement' and 2. If I do not pass the ReportRequestId, I get this error:  Use of undefined constant DATE_FORMAT - assumed 'DATE_FORMAT'. I am all confused

Comment: The first method is correct, namely that you need to pass the ReportRequestID to retrieve that specific order's status.  It sounds like it is a client side exception rather than something that was sent by Amazon.  Search the text of the exception you are getting, and you will find a lot of references to it.  It looks like there may be some placeholder text in the sample PHP library that needs to be replaced.  [AWS Error Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987663/how-submit-amazon-create-fulfilment-order-xml-using-php-api)