# Amazon MWS API returning SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: php, amazon-mws, amazon-product-api

I need to call the Amazon MWS action 'RequestReport' and specify the ReportType as '_GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA_'. i have successfully connected to get the FulfillmentInventory/ListInventorySupply, so i know that the cURL and amazon settings are correct, but every time i submit i get 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.' back from the server. i have tried both sort and ksort on line 23 and 14 - in the call to the FulfillmentInventory/ListInventorySupply i had to set it up with two ksorts in order to keep the list of SKUs in the correct order for the API

Here is the code, as i say, the secret, merchant, and keyid are correct:

```
header('Content-type: application/xml');
$secret = 'secretcodehere';

$param = array();
$param['AWSAccessKeyId']   = 'accessidhere'; 
$param['Action']           = 'RequestReport'; 
$param['Merchant']         = 'merchantidhere';
$param['SignatureVersion'] = '2'; 
$param['Timestamp']        = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());

$param['Version']          = '2009-01-01'; 
$param['SignatureMethod']  = 'HmacSHA256';  
$param['ReportType']  = '_GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA_';  
ksort($param);
$url = array();
foreach ($param as $key => $val) {

    $key = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($key));
    $val = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($val));
    $url[] = "{$key}={$val}";
}

sort($url);

$arr   = implode('&', $url);

$sign  = 'POST' . "\n";
$sign .= 'mws.amazonservices.com';
$sign .= '/doc/2009-01-01' . "\n";
$sign .= $arr;

$signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $sign, $secret, true);
$signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));

$link  = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/doc/2009-01-01/?";
$link .= $arr . "&Signature=" . $signature;
/*

echo($link);//for debugging 

exit(); */

$ch = curl_init($link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($response);
```

i have tried it in MWS scratchpad and the info is correct and generates the 200 response, and when i check the url against the one generated by the scratchpad it 'looks' correct, so i must be missing something and i hope it is obvious to someone out there, 'cause i am baffled.

btw-scratchpad lists it as SellerId, but the url shows it as Merchant - i have tried both with no joy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to throw a curve ball at you, but the only success I've had in using the `RequestReport` has been through using the PHP library that Amazon created. If you don't have it already here's the [link](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/bde/reports/v20090101/php.html/181-5788283-5608455).

This is the code that I just confirmed works to request the report:

```
<?php

define('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', $am_aws_access_key);
define('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', $am_secret_key);
define('MERCHANT_ID', $am_merchant_id);
define('MARKETPLACE_ID', $am_marketplace_id);

include_once ('/link/to/Amazon/library/MarketplaceWebService/Samples/.config.inc.php');

include_once ('functions.php');

$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.com";
$config = array (
    'ServiceURL' => $serviceUrl,
    'ProxyHost' => null,
    'ProxyPort' => -1,
    'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
);
$service = new MarketplaceWebService_Client(
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    $config,
    APPLICATION_NAME,
    APPLICATION_VERSION);

echo '<br />';
$parameters = array (
    'Marketplace' => MARKETPLACE_ID,
    'Merchant' => MERCHANT_ID,
    'ReportType' => '_GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA_',
);

echo '<br /><br/>Request Report Request:<br><br>';
$request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_RequestReportRequest($parameters);
print_r($request);
invokeRequestReport($service, $request);
echo '<br /><br/>';
```

And the `functions.php` file (basically is the important function in the last half of the code in the `MarketplaceWebService\Samples\RequestReportSample.php` file:

```
function invokeRequestReport(MarketplaceWebService_Interface $service, $request)
{
    try {
        $response = $service->requestReport($request);
        echo ("Service Response\n");
        echo ("=============================================================================\n");
        echo("        RequestReportResponse\n");
        if ($response->isSetRequestReportResult()) {
            echo("            RequestReportResult\n");
            $requestReportResult = $response->getRequestReportResult();
            if ($requestReportResult->isSetReportRequestInfo()) {
                $reportRequestInfo = $requestReportResult->getReportRequestInfo();
                echo("                ReportRequestInfo\n");
                if ($reportRequestInfo->isSetReportRequestId())
                {
                    echo("                    ReportRequestId\n");
                    echo("                        " . $reportRequestInfo->getReportRequestId() . "\n");
                }
                $report_request_id = $reportRequestInfo->getReportRequestId();
                $report_type = '';
                if ($reportRequestInfo->isSetReportType())
                {
                    echo("                    ReportType\n");
                    echo("                        " . $reportRequestInfo->getReportType() . "\n");
                    $report_type = $reportRequestInfo->getReportType();
                }
                if ($reportRequestInfo->isSetStartDate())
                {
                    echo("                    StartDate\n");
                    echo("                        " . $reportRequestInfo->getStartDate()->format(DATE_FORMAT) . "\n");
                }
                if ($reportRequestInfo->isSetEndDate())
                {
                    echo("                    EndDate\n");
                    echo("                        " . $reportRequestInfo->getEndDate()->format(DATE_FORMAT) . "\n");
                }
                if ($reportRequestInfo->isSetSubmittedDate())
                {
                    echo("                    SubmittedDate\n");
                    echo("                        " . $reportRequestInfo->getSubmittedDate()->format(DATE_FORMAT) . "\n");
                }
                if ($reportRequestInfo->isSetReportProcessingStatus())
                {
                    echo("                    ReportProcessingStatus\n");
                    echo("                        " . $reportRequestInfo->getReportProcessingStatus() . "\n");
                }
                if($report_type == '_GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA_') {
                    if(!empty($report_request_id)) {
                        $parameters = array (
                            'Marketplace' => MARKETPLACE_ID,
                            'Merchant' => MERCHANT_ID,
                            'Report' => @fopen('php://memory', 'rw+'),
                            'ReportRequestIdList' => $report_request_id,
                        );
                        $report = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_GetReportRequestListRequest($parameters);
                        print_r($report);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if ($response->isSetResponseMetadata()) {
            echo("            ResponseMetadata\n");
            $responseMetadata = $response->getResponseMetadata();
            if ($responseMetadata->isSetRequestId())
            {
                echo("                RequestId\n");
                echo("                    " . $responseMetadata->getRequestId() . "\n");
            }
        }
    } catch (MarketplaceWebService_Exception $ex) {
        echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
        echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
        echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n");
        echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n");
        echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n");
        echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n");
    }
}
```

***EDIT***

Here's the important parts of the `.config.inc.php` file:

```
<?php

define ('DATE_FORMAT', 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');

$app_name = "Just make up a name like 'Awesome Sync'";
$app_version = "1.0";
define('APPLICATION_NAME', $app_name);
define('APPLICATION_VERSION', $app_version);

set_include_path('/link/to/Amazon/library/');
...rest of code...
```

***EDIT***

This code will create the request for the report, however, it doesn't actually create the report. You have to continue to poll Amazon using this same code until you receive a "Complete" or something similar (can't remember the exact word Amazon send back when the report has been created). Then you need to actually retrieve the report.

Comment: thanks for this, what did you use for application name and version (i ask because it is still failing for me) - also, amazon never assigned a marketplace_id - since i am only looking for north america - so i commented it out - it seems like the script is failing on the new MarketplaceWebService_Client call (at least vardump doesn't show anything)

Comment: @user1260414 Just edited my most including the important parts of `.config.inc.php`.

Comment: once i loaded all the rest of amazon's bloated code it worked - thanks for getting me pointed in the right direction!

Comment: @user1260414 Yeah, I'm not a big fan of Amazon's code. I haven't read of anyone who is, to think of it... Glad it helped!

Comment: it does send a complete or ready, but you need the ReportId which i can get from the GetReportList - but now it is throwing an error:Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to construct from provided data. Please be sure to pass associative array or DOMElement'

Comment: I haven't received that error in the past, so I don't know how much help I can be, but here are a couple links that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22029987/652519, https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=100534

Comment: i'm back - asking a follow up - have you ever used the getreportrequestlist command, if you have working code, do you mind sharing it